# C++ class return pointer

Tags: c++, arduino

I believe this could be a duplicate just because I don't knwo what exact terms should I use to google for the right thing.

I'm working with Arduino and I've written library for communication between multiple Arduinos and Raspberries.

```
class Machine {
    public:
        // other functions here
        Mission & create_mission(int num);

    private:
        // other variables here
        Mission _missions[10];
    };
```

And here is the class implementation:

```
    Mission & Machine::create_mission(int num) {
        Mission mission = Mission();
        mission.setNumber(num);
        _missions[_missions_count] = mission;
        _missions_count += 1;

        return _missions[_missions_count-1];
    }
```

As I understand, this:

```
    mission1 = machine.create_mission(1);
```

does not point to the same mission in _missions array within the class Machine.
As I'm not experienced in c++, the question is - how should I implement the function to return the same Mission that's inside the _missions array?

The full code can be downloaded here (.zip): riddle.lv/code/code.zip

Comment: Definition should also return by reference. And currently, you have error as you return reference of temporary object.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? :)

Comment: Why not using `std::array<Mission, 10>` ?

Comment: In declaration, you have: `Mission & create_mission(int num)` and in definition, you have `Mission Machine::create_mission(int num)` (missing reference).

Comment: LeFlou, would that solve the problem?

Comment: Jarod42 - that's not the case, I've tried diffrent approaches. Do you know the correct one?

Comment: @Swagger it is the case, you should return the reference  to your newly created object in the map instead of a reference to the temporary `mission`.

Comment: What I mean is that it still is not working, I'll put the code online somewhere. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in different part of the code

Comment: I've updated the question. Added a link to the code

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
    _missions[_missions_count] = mission;
    _missions_count += 1;

    return _missions[_missions_count-1];
}
```

Also you need to change function signature to

```
  Mission& Machine::create_mission(int num)
```

Comment: This won't work. I believe that it is the same as I've written it so far

Comment: I tested that - it still is not the same object when I do this: mission1 = machine.create_mission(1);

Comment: @Swagger not your whole code, but a [mcve], yes, put it in the question.

Comment: I've added the url to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either return by reference:

Declaration:

```
Mission & create_mission(int num);
```

Definition:

```
  Mission& Machine::create_mission(int num) {
        Mission mission = Mission();
        mission.setNumber(num);
        _missions[_missions_count] = mission;
        _missions_count += 1;

        return _missions[_missions_count - 1];
    }
```

Or by pointer:

Declaration:

```
Mission* create_mission(int num);
```

Definition:

```
Mission* Machine::create_mission(int num) {
            Mission mission = Mission();
            mission.setNumber(num);
            _missions[_missions_count] = mission;
            _missions_count += 1;

            return &_missions[_missions_count - 1];
        }
```

You'd normally return by reference if you expect the object to be there, which is the case here.

Currently, you're returning the reference of a temporary (`mission`) which is not allowed. 
`_missions[_missions_count] = mission;`
Will copy your mission object to the map which will outlive the `create_mission` scope which is what you want.

Comment: When I do this using reference mission1 = machine.create_mission(1); mission1 is not the same object that's inside the class

Comment: @Swagger it is when returning the reference from the map rather than the temporary object.

Comment: @Arkadiy It doesn't? it returns a reference to the copied map object. Recheck the code.

Comment: @JameyD Right you are, deleting my comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new Mission object and assigns it to one in your list. Then this *temporary* object will be returned. Furthermore the `create_mission()` method is declared to return a *copy* of a `Mission`object.

You can circumvent this by working with references like this:

```
 Mission &Machine::create_mission(int num) {
    // create a reference to one of the Missions in the array
    Mission &mission = _missions[_missions_count];
    // work on that Mission
    mission.setNumber(num);
    _missions_count += 1
    // return the reference;
    return mission;
}
```